# SQL Bigquery returning null results even though I am using IS NOT NULL statement

Tags: sql, null, google-bigquery

In Bigquery, I am receiving rows where the value is Null even though I have placed an IS NOT NULL statement in my query.

```
SELECT 
country,
region,
region_name
FROM `table`
WHERE region_name IS NOT NULL
AND country LIKE 'DE'
GROUP BY 2, 3, 1
```

When I pull this however, I still receive a row where region and region name are NULL but country is not. Is there something obvious I am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you are observing empty strings that are not `NULL`. One way to confirm this is by adding in your `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE
region_name IS NOT NULL and region_name != ''
AND country LIKE 'DE'
```

Comment: Wow that is amazing. worked for me! Why does bigquery not treat an empty string as a NULL? whats the difference?

Comment: glad it worked :). Check this out for a better understanding of their difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651685/empty-string-vs-null

Comment: If the value is the string, `null`, it will render as _null_ in the BQ UI, misleading the user into believing that the value is `NULL`